# Adding activity indicator on webview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uiwebview

i m parsing an rss feed and loading in a webview...wat i want is ..to place a custom activity indicator in the exact place..where the parsing begins and the place where the parsing ends....below is the code.

```
@implementation MenuAndWineListViewController

NSDictionary *dict;

UIAlertView * errorAlert;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    self.title=@"Menu & WineList";  
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    activityIndicator1 = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]autorelease];

    activityIndicator1.frame=CGRectMake(0.0,0.0, 40.0, 40.0);

    activityIndicator1.center=self.view.center;

    [self.view addSubview:activityIndicator1];

    NSURL *baseURL=[[NSURL 

    URLWithString:@"http://www.riverstonechophouse.com.php5-22.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com /?feedpages&max=0&sort_order=ASC&parent=12&child_of=12"]retain];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    connection1=[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

    if ([stories count] == 0) {

        path = @"http://www.riverstonechophouse.com.php5-22.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/?feedpages&max=0&

        sort_order=ASC&parent=180&child_of=180";

        [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];
    }

    [menuAndWineListViewController loadHTMLString:[dict objectForKey:@"description"]  baseURL:nil];

    [menuAndWineListViewController setClipsToBounds:YES];

     menuAndWineListViewController.opaque=NO;

     menuAndWineListViewController.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    [menuAndWineListViewController setDelegate:self];
}


- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}


- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{   
    NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");   
}

- (void)parseXMLFileAtURL:(NSString *)URL
{   
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];

    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlURL];

    [rssParser setDelegate:self];

    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];

    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];

    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [rssParser parse];
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI: (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{           
    currentElement = [elementName copy];

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
    {
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{     

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
    {
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"description"];
        [stories addObject:[item copy]];
    }

    for (i=0 ; i<stories.count;i++) 
    {
        dict = [stories objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{   
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
    {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    }

    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"description"]) 
    {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } 
}


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    [activityIndicator1 stopAnimating];

    [activityIndicator1 removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"stories array has %d items", [stories count]);
}
```

Comment: please use thr {} button or 4 spaces for indentation level to format your code next time. I think what you like to achieve is easy but the sheer mass of code may drive people away so start simple, and when the comments and answers come you can refine your question and add more detail if necessary.

Comment: now to you question: Do you need a UIActivityIndicator or an animated gif in your webview?

Comment: @Nick:mkay...wat i want is an animated activity indicator..i wanna know which place exactly i gotta use this [activityIndicator1 startAnimating] and [activityIndicator1 stopanimating]..in the abve code...works fine for table view.....

Comment: what happens if stories is greater than 0? You don't use the nsurlconnection right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put the

```
[activityIndicator1 startAnimating];
```

at the beginning of the `parseXMLFileAtURL` method

and the

```
[activityIndicator1 stopanimating];
```

at the beginning of the `parserDidEndDocument` like you did.

Comment: @kingston Does the app crash? you are autoreleasing `activityIndicator1` after creation and you don't retain it. Have you tried the other styles? Try to add only the indicator to your view first and see if it shows up.

Comment: i m not getting any crash..the same above code for activityindicator works good for parsing and loading data in tableview....but for webview..i m not able to get the activityindicator spinning

Comment: @kingston are you adding the indicator to your webview as subview?

Comment: @Nick:thanks man that totally worked....i added [activityIndicator1 startAnimating] after activity indicator creation in viewdidload...and added webview as my subview

Comment: @Nick...is it anyway possible to place an activity indicator on tabbaritem...ive got four tabbar the third one has got scroll view which loads high reslution image from resorce bundle..if i m to tap the tab bar..the screen remains frozen for a second then shows the content of the third tabbar ..have any idea...:))

Comment: @kingston as far as I know you can't add an indicator to a tabbaritem. But you can add an indicator to a container view which holds the scrollview.

Comment: mkay...i m an noob...dis is a totally irrelevant question am i supposed to create distributor certificate for each new app i develop..or onesingle distibutor certificate can be reused in different apps that i develop